# Could I overload operator= to assign object of a class to a variable of another class but both class are from the same class template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, template-specialization

For example, I have a class

```
template<class T>
class Number
{
private:
    T number;
public:
    Number(T num)
    {
        number=num;
    }
    void operator=(T num)
    {
        number=num;
    }
}
```

how can I overload the assign operator to assign a Number<char> object to a variable of type Number<int>, or specialize a method of one type with the parametres of another type of the same template? By the way, is it possible to make an alias of class template, Number<char>, as "MyChar" so I don't need to use the class name Number<char> anymore but the alias MyChar

Comment: you can make a template alias by using the... `using` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make assignment operator a template member function with a separate type parameter:

```
// Make sure the template on U can access private number
template <class U> friend class Number;

template<class U>
Number<T>& operator=(const Number<U>& num)
{
    number = static_cast<T>(num.number);
    return *this;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/aiUMEG)

Comment: Ahh, beat me by seconds. Good answer, +1. But probably a `static_cast` would've been better, than the c-style cast. EDIT: what is interesting, is the fact that when we do that with different class specialisations, i.e. `Number<int>` and `Number<char>`, there occurr private access issues. Actually these two instations are of different classes, so they can't access private data. There is a need for making a getter function

Comment: @Fureeish You are right about static cast, thank you very much!

Comment: @Fureeish Thank you again. I added a template friend declaration to solve this problem.

Comment: Wow I actually didn't think about that solution. It is **way** better than simply making a getter, since it is not always desired to provide read access. Great answer!

Comment: The answer for my last question is "typedef"

Comment: @StephenKhoa you cannot make a templated `typedef`. You can make a templated `using`